# Launchct GD Extension with Freetype support not working on php

Tags: terminal, launchd, php

I'm Running a .plist php file

previously, I've installed phpbrew and use 7.3.11 php version.

Then I've just installed GD extension with freetype support

I can running my php files into Macos terminal with not problem at all using GD Extension.

As we can see here:

```
juanpro@MacBook-Air-de-juanpro ~ % php /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/alert/imagen.php
Array
(
[GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
[FreeType Support] => 1
[FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
[GIF Read Support] => 1
[GIF Create Support] => 1
[JPEG Support] => 1
[PNG Support] => 1
[WBMP Support] => 1
[XPM Support] => 
[XBM Support] => 1
[WebP Support] => 
[BMP Support] => 1
[TGA Read Support] => 1
[JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
FreeType Support Enabled
```

But if I Schedule the same file I don't get the desired output, apparently the GD extension is not running.

**What I tried to do**

My first thought was a permission problem

So a check all folder and file permissions. Then I check my .plist permissions as well, then Ive use chown root chgrp wheel.

Nothing Works.

So, Ive just wondering about creating a log file in order to see the error output (I'm a lawyer but do my best try), so a Put some lines into the Plist file and finally I can see the output

```
Array
(
[GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
[FreeType Support] => 
[GIF Read Support] => 1
[GIF Create Support] => 1
[JPEG Support] => 1
[PNG Support] => 1
[WBMP Support] => 1
[XPM Support] => 
[XBM Support] => 1
[WebP Support] => 
[BMP Support] => 1
[JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

This was totally weird to me, Because same file executes with not problem directly into terminal.

So, I thought: Maybe, Launchctl are using another php versión

Then I Use a PHP Code into my file to see what version are actually running and I getting this:

```
Core => 7.3.11<br/>date => 7.3.11<br/>libxml => 7.3.11<br/>openssl => 7.3.11<br/>pcre => 7.3.11<br/>sqlite3 => 7.3.11<br/>zlib => 7.3.11<br/>bcmath => 7.3.11<br/>bz2 => 7.3.11<br/>calendar => 7.3.11<br/>ctype => 7.3.11<br/>curl => 7.3.11<br/>dba => 7.3.11<br/>dom => 20031129<br/>hash => 7.3.11<br/>fileinfo => 7.3.11<br/>filter => 7.3.11<br/>ftp => 7.3.11<br/>gd => 7.3.11<br/>SPL => 7.3.11<br/>iconv => 7.3.11<br/>json => 1.7.0<br/>ldap => 7.3.11<br/>mbstring => 7.3.11<br/>session => 7.3.11<br/>standard => 7.3.11<br/>mysqlnd => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $<br/>PDO => 7.3.11<br/>pdo_mysql => 7.3.11<br/>pdo_pgsql => 7.3.11<br/>pdo_sqlite => 7.3.11<br/>pgsql => 7.3.11<br/>Phar => 7.3.11<br/>posix => 7.3.11<br/>readline => 7.3.11<br/>Reflection => 7.3.11<br/>mysqli => 7.3.11<br/>shmop => 7.3.11<br/>SimpleXML => 7.3.11<br/>snmp => 7.3.11<br/>soap => 7.3.11<br/>sockets => 7.3.11<br/>exif => 7.3.11<br/>sysvmsg => 7.3.11<br/>sysvsem => 7.3.11<br/>sysvshm => 7.3.11<br/>tidy => 7.3.11<br/>tokenizer => 7.3.11<br/>wddx => 7.3.11<br/>xml => 7.3.11<br/>xmlreader => 7.3.11<br/>xmlrpc => 7.3.11<br/>xmlwriter => 7.3.11<br/>xsl => 7.3.11<br/>
enter code here
```

**So, this is a mistery to me, because I really don't know why Launchctl refuses to uses the GD extension with freetype support previously installed in that version (it works only without freetype). ¿Am I forgetting something? Thanks in advance**

Comment: How do you shedule the program - I suspect they way you do it has a different PATH to the terminal

Comment: @mmmmmm launchctl load -w /Users/juanpro/Library/LaunchAgents/com.plisterine.cuenta.plist

Comment: @mmmmmm I have no problem with the schedule the file are running but without the freetype support.

Comment: I suspect you are not running the php you expect - what is in the plist

Comment: @mmmmmm i really dont know why youre suspect that I mean, I literrally executing part of the code of my php file. The problem its that the freetype part.